# Joining Two SQL Table - Group By Column from table 1 Not From table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I want to select the following columns from the customer table into a new table called #Demographics

```
# Table customer 
select cu.creationDate, cu.personId
    ,       cu.age as age
    ,       cu.gender as gender
    ,       cu.ageCategory as ageCategory
    into #Demographics
    from dbo.customer cu with (nolock)
```

Now, I want to join #Demographics table to another table called on Bills with some conditions and then group by columns I have in Bill table.

```
# Join To table Bill - not using table customer in grouping argument 
select Bill.Id
,       Bill.Subs
,       Bill.billNumber
,       Bill.billDateBegin
,       Bill.billDateEnd
,       Dem.age
,       Dem.ageCategory 
,       Dem.gender
into   #Demographics2
from dbo.Bill Bill
left join #Demographics Dem on Bill.Id = Dem.Id
and Dem.creationDate >= Bill.billDateBegin
and Dem.creationDate < Bill.billDateEnd
where 1=1
group by Bill.Id
,       Bill.Subs
,       Bill.billNumber
,       Bill.billDateBegin
,       Bill.billDateEnd
order by Id, billNumber
```

However, I don't want to use columns from #Demographics table for grouping. But I get error

```
 The multi-part identifier … could not be bound in Join statements
```

- Is this right approach?
- Can someone suggest me a way of joining the table as I want to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. But first take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Use any aggregrate function() for #Demographics table.

Comment: You use `left join #Demographics Dem on Bill.Id = Dem.Id` but `#Demographics` doesn't contain an `Id` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the scenario mention by you, you may try this. Since in `#Demographics` you have your customer details so using of max will give you same record for each customer.

```
select Bill.Id
,       Bill.Subs
,       Bill.billNumber
,       Bill.billDateBegin
,       Bill.billDateEnd
,       Max(Dem.age) as age
,       Max(Dem.ageCategory) as ageCategory  
,       Max(Dem.gender) as gender
into   #Demographics2
from dbo.Bill Bill
left join #Demographics Dem on Bill.Id = Dem.Id
and Dem.creationDate >= Bill.billDateBegin
and Dem.creationDate < Bill.billDateEnd
where 1=1
group by Bill.Id
,       Bill.Subs
,       Bill.billNumber
,       Bill.billDateBegin
,       Bill.billDateEnd
order by Id, billNumber
```

In using `group by` you must select same column names in your `select` statement and `group by` clause. Since you don't want to select your columns so must apply some agregate function on the remaining columns like `sum, max, min... etc`.
You may check this link for more info on Group By [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).